# Collection View does not reload after in-app Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, uicollectionview

I dont understand why my collectionview dont reload when the transaction was finished.

```
-(void)finishedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction{
//code
    [self reload];
}

-(void)reload{
    [_myCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

i try with backgroundSelections, NStimer etc and its very weird because the function runs.

if i create a button and press, the collection reload very well, but want the collection reload automatically when finishedTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reload) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Maybe your are facing some problem changing some UI element in background, from the piece of code that you put here it is hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a xib you need to make sure you've set the IBOutlet in Interface Builder. I had this same problem with a UIKit element not updating, til I realized I didn't have the IBOutlet set in IB.